# How to get the X,Y position of a UserControl within a Canvas

Tags: wpf, user-controls, attached-properties

I have a simple UserControl as below - that I place in a Canvas.  I move it using Multi-touch and I want to be able to read its new X,Y postion using procedural C# code.  Ideally I would like to have X and Y as two properties or as a Point (X,Y).

```
<UserControl x:Class="TouchControlLibrary.myControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="64" d:DesignWidth="104">
    <Border Name="ControlBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
        <DockPanel Margin="1" Height="60 " Width="100">
            <StackPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Gray"  Width="20" >
                <Button Background="#FFDEDE53" Padding="0">In</Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="Gray"  Width="20" >
                <Button Background="#FFE8B48F" Padding="0">Out</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>  
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

I expected to create an attached property for each of 'X' and 'Y' and fill them from Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top, using binding or some form of attached property or ???.   I have spent quite some time searching for a solution, but everything I find seems to be 'not quite what is needed'.

Comment: So, why don't you just use the Canvas.Left and Top properties?

Comment: I have multiple instances of my UserControl and Canvas.left does not exist.   I did try Canvas.Getleft(myControl1), and while it returned a value, this did not chnage as I moved the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two properties like this in your userControl,

```
    public double Top
    {
        get
        {
            if (double.IsNaN(Canvas.GetTop(this)))
            {
                return (double)0;
            }
            return Canvas.GetTop(this);
        }

        set
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(this, value);
        }
    }
```

The check for "NotANumber" is not realy necessary, but I use it to prevent errors.

Comment: I added this and it did return the correct 'Top' value, however when I moved the control this was not reflected in the property value that is, it did not change.  .  My main program does have a Canvas with a Canvas within it, and the Control is within the inner Canvas.

Comment: Could it be, that you are moving the Canvas Containing your Control together with your control?

Comment: No, it is moving within the inner Canvas, and if I move the inner canvas the control moves with it.  Also I just moved the inner canvas and the Top property returned the same initial value.   If I change the usercontrol position before I run the program it does change - so in effect I get the intial X,Y - but not the change.    Seems like I need to invoke the 'depenency property' in some way.

Comment: Very strange as I took my example out of a programm of me, wich works fine

Comment: Sure, I will try to add it in .. (first time ever for StackOverFlow so bear with me.  The movement is done by multi-touch under Windows 7, so it is lengthy...  basically in the ManipulationDelta event I get the usercontrol (called encryptor) information - and use the incrmental movement to do a tranform on the control. So here it is ...

Comment: sorry - perhaps an explanation!    In the event, the following 4 lines do it all;

Comment: Perhaps you edit your first post and instert the code block for improved readability ;-)

Comment: MatrixTransform transformMatrix = element.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;

    //If it exists,
    if (transformMatrix != null)
           {
              //Then retrieve the matrix from it
              matrix = transformMatrix.Matrix;
           }
          //Apply the delta translation
          matrix.Translate(e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X, e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);

Comment: how do you go back and edit the first block?     Anyway, all the code of the main program does is handle the delta event that applies the X,Y chnage via the transform.   That works, so  think it has to do with the 'Top' property not changing - and I can't see why it would - unless somehow it gets a callback??

Comment: As far as i can see your code, i think you don't really move your controll, you translate it - this is a big difference! Try to set the Canvas.Top and Left direct in your Movement function, I think this should get you to success.

Comment: BTW. you can edit your block by clicking on "edit" below your question

Comment: thanks .. I will try ...  what does work is the following in my movement function:

Comment: Mp = element.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), null);
where element is my control, MP is a Point and I use Mp.X and Mp.Y to get the positon.   I really wanted to encapsulate it all in the control however that does appear difficult.

Comment: try "element.Top = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X; element.Left = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y" where Top and Left are my suggestet properties.

Comment: These return the incrmental X,Y movement since the last delta event - there are the cumulative ones, however they still require that you can access the origianl X,Y position to get the real new X,Y.   The TranslatePoint' does give me this, but it's just in my movement code, not in the actual control.

Comment: well, why not? Is there a reason, why the movement code is not in the control?

Comment: No, perhaps not!  My thinking may have been wrong - perhaps it will be easier to work with an inside X,Y along with the parents properties.  (I am in Australia - most likely many hours out of sync with you).  Also while a little unrelated to this, I am no longer keen on my control-inside canvas-inside canvas model.  I think I should be using a hierarchical control (treeview) inside a canvas and then adding template to get what I am aiming for..... so thanks, for now I will try what you suggest

Comment: well, you are really on the other site of the globe ;-)

Comment: yes .... your input has pointed me in the right direction.  I am getting there.  I will update when I have it all in place.  thanks...